# Seat Post Binder - Fuji CF1 - circa 2008

Tags: parts, seatpost, replacement

I'm looking for a replacement seat binder for a 2008 Fuji Aloha CF1 - The one I had cracked and will no longer work.

I have contacted Fuji but they politely laughed at us!

Most shops looked through their "junk" cabinets with no luck.

What can I do to replace the seat clamp?

[image: 2008 Fuji Aloha CF1]

Here is the photo of the seat clamp.

[image: Seat Clamp]

Comment: Hi Mark - I'm going to combine your answer into your question, and add some more info.  If I error or loose your meaning then please use revert or edit again.  The one thing that would make this better is a clear photo of your existing seat clamp showing how it broke.

Comment: Go to a hardware store and get a spiral hose clamp.

Comment: Looking at pictures on the web I see several different setups for the seatpost.  With some the clamp appears to be an entirely separate piece, with some it appears to be a clamp around the top of the seat tube, and with some it appears to be integrated into the seat tube.  A *close-up* picture of your clamp would be most helpful.

Comment: I think this question is totally on-topic. albeit lacking a photo of the damaged clamp.

Comment: It's not clear where the clamp broke.

Answer (score 2):

The Fuji Aloha is a Tri-bike with a aero shaped seat tube, therefore a generic replacement binder for a regular circular seat post will not work,

You will probably have to contact a bike store that carries Fuji products (at the time of writing that is [Performance Bikes](http://www.performancebike.com)) or [Fuji Bikes](http://www.fujibikes.com/usa/) directly to order a replacement.

---

Update - because apparently neither Fuji nor Performance can help.

If a replacement really cannot be found, you could try finding a machine shop that will do custom small orders. A competent shop with a small CNC machine should be able to create a binder using the damaged one as a pattern.

Comment: You really don’t need a CNC mill for a one off.

Comment: Yes, but it will make machining the aero shape of the seatpost and seat tube *a lot* easier!

Comment: It is service like this that puts people off a brand for life.

Comment: BTW: is there a technical reason for the front quick release to be at the right side and pointing forward?

Comment: @Carel Does "The wheel was put on backwards" count as a technical reason? :-) But, regardless of which side it's on, having it face forwards is a bad idea in case it catches on something (whether or not that results in the QR being opened).

Comment: @DavidRicherby: didn't even want to mention that, but of course, yes! :-D

Answer (score -1):

Through face book found a contact at a distributor....came up with a part # - SP8035

Using that part number we found out they had it in stock....ordered 2!

#feelinglucky

Comment: Its not a great answer but it is an answer and what worked for OP.  Plus it shows the exact part number for this bike so that is useful information.